# python pip silent install

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to do a silent install with pip?

For some more background I'm using fabric to do server deployments and I want to be able to setup a new server or update an existing one without any interaction and some of the packages require a y/n response.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A silent install is possible by using the **`quiet`** (short: `q`) flag:

```
pip install somepackage --quiet
```

This hides installation messages.
As per [its documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#quiet), note that this option is additive, and can be specified up to 3 times to remove messages of increasing levels of importance (warning, error, critical).

Additionally, you may want to force "always yes" as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8400396), and/or an [`exists-action` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/#exists-action-option) for a default behaviour when multiple choices exist:

```
yes | pip install somepackage -q -q -q --exists-action i
```

where `exists-action i` stands for *ignore*, and 3 `quiet`s hide every message.

This truly has its mouth shut!

Comment: It errored: `option --exists-action: invalid choice: 'ignore' (choose from 's', 'i', 'w', 'b', 'a')`. Shouldn’t it be `--exists-action i`?

Answer (score 41):

If the answer is always `y`:

```
yes | pip install <package>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the main blocker for an unattended run I've found is this question: "What to do?  (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup"

Comment: Is there an equivalent in windows cmd ?

Comment: Note that it does *not* work in some scenarios, such as a SSH prompt (ie: `The authenticity of host 'example.net (192.0.2.1)' can't be established. ... Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?`), at least in pip 1.5.4.

Comment: Also only works in *NIX.  Its too bad pip does not have a built in (therefore cross platform) means of doing this.

Answer (score 6):

Adding an answer, since things have changes since 2011...

Pip version [1.1 release on 2012-02-16](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#id169) has introduced a command line switch `--exists-action <action>` which allows to specify the default behavior from (s)witch, (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup, (a)bort.

According to the [current documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/) pip can only prompt for information if `--exists-action` is unspecified.