# pip install & uninstall recursively in non-interactive mode

Tags: python, pip

As a part of my bash script, I want to install and uninstall pip dependencies that I have their names in a file in a non-interactive mode. I was able to search around and find these commands:

```
pip3 uninstall --yes -r host-requirements.txt
pip3 install --no-input -r host-requirements.txt
```

I wasn't able to find `--yes` & `--no-input` options in the help doc of pip, and I'm not sure if they are officially supported.

Comment: This is correct. They are supported `--no-input` here https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py#L219 and `--yes` here https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py#L39

Comment: I'm wondering why it isn't in the official doc. Does it mean they may stop supporting it without notice?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For uninstall, you can use the `--yes` or `-y` flag as described here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/

For installation, you can pass a `yes | pip install -r requirements.txt` as described here: [python pip silent install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400382/python-pip-silent-install/8400396#8400396)

Hope this helps.

Comment: apparently `yes` doesn't work for some scenarios, as mentioned in the comment of the post you gave a link to.

Comment: Correct but `yes` should work for pip installs. It is not going to work for when, like in the example, you want to confirm the authenticity of a server.

Comment: Checking the authenticity of server is something that we control? is it possible that simple `pip install -r` gets into that situation ?

Comment: It does not get into that situation unless there is a man in the middle attack, and you are not using https, which you are. When you run pip install, pip automatically goes out to the python package index (pypi.org) and grabs the package UNLESS you specify a different index. It is unlikely, IMO, that you are specifying an index.

Answer (score 2):

There are more interactive questions that expect other answers than "yes". For instance:

```
Directory /opt/services/spam/egg already exists, and is not a git clone.
What to do?  (i)gnore, (w)ipe, (b)ackup`
```

In such scenario I found calling `echo "i" | pip install ...` was sufficient.

Comment: There is a [`--exists-action` option](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#exists-action-option).

Answer (score 1):

A common issue on install is if there is a private repository dependency that has to be resolved and the key of the remote server has to be initially added.

```
Obtaining file://...
Collecting your_private_package@ git+ssh://...
  Cloning ssh://****@.../
  Running command git clone -q 'ssh://****@.../
The authenticity of host can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ...
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

For this, ssh `StrictHostKeyChecking` would be temporarily set to no.  This can be done at the host or user level at the risk of less security.