# PyQt5 is waiting for input, when installing via pip

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to install PyQt5 into an conda env (I need pyqt installed via pip and the same error happens with a "normal" Python `venv`. First I got a real quick error message, which is solved by installing qt5 via brew (`brew install qt5`). When I now try to create the environment with pyqt5 directly using a yaml file, it takes ages and then pip is killed (`killed: 9`). If I try to install it manually using `pip install pyqt5==5.15.9` I get the following output:

```
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.9
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
```

At this point nothing happens anymore (I guess, it would be killed, if I waited longer). If I install using `pip install pyqt5==5.15.9 -v` it shows:

```
...
  Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
  This is the GPL version of PyQt 5.15.9 (licensed under the GNU General Public License) for Python 3.10.12 on darwin.

  Type 'L' to view the license.
  Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
  Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.
```

And nothing happens from here on. Of course, I tried to type `yes`, but nothing happened. Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install & uninstall recursively in non-interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56382958/pip-install-uninstall-recursively-in-non-interactive-mode)

Comment: If Conda is only being used for Python, then this doesn't need a Conda tag, rather just mention it in the body. Otherwise, this will attract people (like me) asking, "*Why are three package managers being used in the first place?*" Conda can handle all this: `conda create -n envname -c conda-forge python=3.11 pyqt=5.15.9`

Comment: You're totally right. The conda tag is misguiding. I actually have the same issue in a "normal" Python venv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install pyqt5, it cannot go on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73714829/pip-install-pyqt5-it-cannot-go-on)

Comment: Also found this. I'm gonna try it later :). Thanks